# Android's ViewFlipper alternative on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

The [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) on Android has very a simple API that allows you to show a view from a list of children at a time. You're also able to know what view is being shown to the user programmatically, as well as set up an animation between its transitions, is there a widget that does this similarly in Flutter?
Below is an excerpt from the `ViewFlipper` documentation.

> Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that
>   have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to swap between 2 views, is the [AnimatedCrossFade](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedCrossFade-class.html).

> A widget that cross-fades between two given children and animates
>   itself between their sizes.

This widget is an enhanced [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) and is similar to the `ViewFlipper` because it takes charge of swapping between 2 views depending on a state by interpolating its sizes and opacities.

---

This is an example of a simple `AnimatedCrossFade` that switches between 2 `Containers` of different colors and sizes.

```dart
class MySimpleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MySimpleWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MySimpleWidgetState createState() => _MySimpleWidgetState();
}

class _MySimpleWidgetState extends State<MySimpleWidget> {
  bool _showFirst = false;

  void _swapWidget() {
    setState(() {
      _showFirst = !_showFirst;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedCrossFade(
            crossFadeState: _showFirst ? CrossFadeState.showFirst : CrossFadeState.showSecond,
            firstChild: Container(color: Colors.red, width: 100, height: 50),
            secondChild: Container(color: Colors.blue, width: 100, height: 100),
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            onPressed: _swapWidget,
            child: const Text('Swap widget'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

Its limitation is that it can only crossfade between 2 children, an alternative for 3 or more could be the [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom logic using stateful widget:

```dart
// define controller for changing child
final ViewSwitcherController controller = ViewSwitcherController();

// custom ViewFlipper widget
ViewFlipper(controller: controller, children: [....]);

// change child sample
controller.setDisplayedChild(index);
```

**viewflipper.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class ViewFlipper extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final ViewSwitcherController controller;

  const ViewFlipper(
      {Key? key, required this.children, required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ViewFlipper> createState() => _ViewFlipperState();
}

class _ViewFlipperState extends State<ViewFlipper> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.children[widget.controller.displayedChildIndex];
  }
}

class ViewSwitcherController extends ChangeNotifier {
  int displayedChildIndex = 0;

  void setDisplayedChild(int index) {
    displayedChildIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```